# Incremental looping

Tags: javascript, loops, increment

I have the following code:

```
if((dropdown1save=="1")&&(dropdown2save=="1")&&(dropdown3save=="1")){
    $('#feedbackbox').html(information[1]);
}

if((dropdown1save=="1")&&(dropdown2save=="1")&&(dropdown3save=="2")){
    $('#feedbackbox').html(information[2]);
  }
```

dropdown1save goes from 1 to 3
dropdown2save goes from 1 to 10
dropdown3save goes from 1 to 20

I need a loop whereby dropdown3save loops from 1 - 20 then dropdown2save goes up 1 and dropdown3 loops again

Then when dropdown2save has reached 10 dropdown1save goes up one and the loop for each one begins again

for example 
111 
112 (and so on until)
121
122 (and so on until
211
212 (etc)

every time the dropdown3save  loops i need (information[x]] to go up 1 too (This will therefore go up to 600 as there are There are 600 combinations!)

Sorry thats a lot to figure out but I have no idea how to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
$('#feedbackbox').html(
    information[
        ((parseInt(dropdown1save) - 1)  * (10 * 20) ) + 
        ((parseInt(dropdown2save) - 1)  * 20) +
        parseInt(dropdown3save)
    ]
);
```

Comment: Correct approach - your actual arithmetic might need work, though.

Comment: Your first one should be `*10*20`, not just `*10` - otherwise `(3,1,1) == (1,2,1)`

Comment: For extra style points, I would say: (1) use an intermediate variable for the index, it'll be easier to read, and (2) `parseInt()` should always be used with a second argument by habit, otherwise it will one day trip you up when you're not looking.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a looping. The following set of `for` statements will loop through the values from 1 to 20, then increase the value of j by one and loop from 1 to 20 again. Then when the value of j hits 10, it will increment i by one and repeat.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        for (var k = 1; k < 20; k++) {
            count = i * j * k;
            if (dropdown1save == i.toString() && dropdown2save == j.toString() && dropdown3save == k.toString())
            {
                $("#feedbackbox").html(information[count]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Hi this looks good. However Dropdown1save etc is the value of local storage so its asking if the local storage key is a number not just any number

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=1; i<= 3; i++) {
    for(var j=1; j<= 10; j++) {
            for(var k=1;k<=20;k++) {
                    if((dropdown1save==i.toString() )&& (dropdown2save==j.toString()) && (dropdown3save==k.toString())){
                            $('#feedbackbox').html(information[200*(i-1) + 20*(j-1) + k]);
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tend to avoid `cnt` as a variable name because it looks very much like a profanity. (We Brits do swear quite intensely, so it's a simple association.)  :p

Comment: @cloudfeet check it now!

Comment: I actually preferred it with a separate variable - it was easier to read.  I was simply saying that I think you should call the variable `count`, not `cnt`. :)